# Chrome 45 CSP child-src for blob

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker, content-security-policy

I updated to Chrome 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) and my child-src policy for blobs no longer works.

The error:

`Refused to create a child context containing 'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/80ec57ff-e6ae-4591-8526-6c9f0c412b51' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self' http://localhost:3000 blob:http://localhost:3000 blob:http://localhost 'blob://localhost:3000'".`

As you can see I've tried a few different policies.

- http://localhost:3000
- blob:http://localhost:3000
- blob:http://localhost
- 'blob://localhost:3000'

What child-src policy do I need to add so I can run javascript blobs on localhost:3000?

Comment: where have u added these policies?

Answer (score 3):

Add `blob:` to child-src.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#endnote_2

Comment: Where should i added this policy?